# Emacs disable auto-complete in python-mode

Tags: emacs

I am using Emacs 24 and would like to disable auto-complete mode while in python-mode so it does not conflict with jedi. How do I go about doing this (sadly I do not know Emacs Lisp). Below are my current settings regarding auto-complete in init.el:

```
;; auto-complete settings
(require 'auto-complete)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
; Start auto-completion after 2 characters of a word
(setq ac-auto-start 2)
; case sensitivity is important when finding matches
(setq ac-ignore-case nil)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you meanm conflicts? Jedi.el itself uses auto-complete-mode. If you disable it, it won't be able to show completions.

Comment: In addition to comment by Dmitry: can't see any conflict from python-mode.el with jedi.

Answer (score 6):

`(ac-config-default)` turns on `global-auto-complete-mode`, to stop `(auto-complete-mode)` from being called in python mode you can write an advice for it.

```
(defadvice auto-complete-mode (around disable-auto-complete-for-python)
  (unless (eq major-mode 'python-mode) ad-do-it))

(ad-activate 'auto-complete-mode)
```

Also I am not sure this is what you want, since Jedi use auto-complete-mode as Dmitry pointed out in the comment, there should not be conflicts.

Answer (score 5):

I think I had a similar problem: my yellow Jedi popups with Python-specific content were taken over by grey popups from a more general auto-complete feature.  Hence, I could choose non-Python related options, but not the Python-specific ones.

What helped for me was ensuring that auto-complete-mode is disabled in Python mode:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda () (auto-complete-mode -1)))
```