# disable autocomplete for specific filetype or language in emacs

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I'm trying to configure emacs so that the autocomplete mode doesn't trigger on .py files only (i do use it for javascript and would like to keep it)
Is there a way to achieve this? I can't seem to find an exemple or the relevant documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814988/emacs-disable-auto-complete-in-python-mode

Comment: thanks @bznein, the solution given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814988/emacs-disable-auto-complete-in-python-mode) worked well